# how to control textbox type to double in visual basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, double

I'd like to make a textbox that accepts only numbers, but not integer, but rather double.
I've read here about `e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)` and it works, but again, it can be used only for integer, since it declines decimal point.
Another thing I've read here is `If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, value) Then ....` and it would work fine, except that it allows only decimal comma instead of point. I don't know whether it's because of my location settings (Hungary, we use commas instead of points), but I don't have any other idea how to solve my problem, and the SQL server I send my data uses decimal point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `TryParse`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really make it, it seems.  
I tried to follow the guide VB gives and I came up with something like this: "If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, style:=NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, provider:=CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, result:=value)", but it still converts my decimal point to comma. :(  
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you call `ToString`, you need to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` there, too.  Where is it getting converted to a comma?

Comment: OMG! You are awesome! Thanks, it works perfectly!
Btw, passing the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture also to ToString was the solution. :)